# Date and time mix up in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, string-to-datetime

Please consider below Dataset,
[image]

The column with dates is 'Date Announced' ,current date format id 'DD-MM-YYYY' i want to change the date format to 'MM/DD/YYYY'.
To do so i have written the following pandas code,

```
df3=pd.read_csv('raw_data_27th_APRonwards.csv',parse_dates=[0], dayfirst=True)
df3['Date Announced'] = pd.to_datetime(df3['Date Announced'])
df3['Date Announced'] = df3['Date Announced'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

Post executing above code, i didn't get the desired output, please consider below Dataset,
[image]

Notice in the output, Date '09/05/2020'is coming wrong , it should be like '05/09/2020' , there is a mix up btw date and month for this particular date. how to fix this?

Comment: in the first line of your code, you specify `parse_dates=[0], dayfirst=True` - so the column at index 0 should be parsed correctly. is that the case? I assume 'Date Announced' is at a different index; you might want to specify `dayfirst=True` here as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this :

```
df3['Date Announced'] = pd.to_datetime(df3['Date Announced'], format='%d-%m-%Y')
```

Now :

```
df3['Date Announced'] = df3['Date Announced'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

or pass `parse_dates` parameter while reading csv file like this:

```
pd.read_csv('your_file.csv', parse_dates=['Date Announced'])
```